# I need to share multiple images using facebook

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

In my website there is shopping cart. if shopping cart contain 4 products then 4 images will be share on facebook at once.

right now am using the below code but its not working properly

```
<?php 
$facebook = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://server.ashoresystems.com/~crookedt/index.php?option=com_easydiscuss&view=post";
?>
```

below url is a screenshot of the page.

please help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Here is my Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">  
<?php
                    $title=urlencode('Title of Your iFrame Tab');
                    //$url=urlencode('http://www.facebook.com/yourfanpage');
                    $url=urlencode('http://www.kokopame.com');
                    $summary=urlencode('Custom message that summarizes what your tab is about, or just a simple message to tell people to check out your tab.');

                ?>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Kokopame</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Title of Your iFrame Tab"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Custom message that summarizes what your tab is about, to tell people to check out your tab."/>


        <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.decibio.com/store/report_icon/medium/1375336395_Rx Tools report icon.jpg" />
        <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.decibio.com/store/report_icon/medium/1370905582_NGS.jpg" />

        </head>
    <body>


    <?php $url = urlencode('http://www.kokopame.com/test_share_images.php'); ?>

     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $url;?>" target="_blank" >Share Metadata Example111</a><br/>

     <?php //echo file_get_contents('https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kokopame.com%2Ftest_share_images.php');?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: You can't share more than one image with that old sharer.php. You need to use the Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: can you please provide the actual link where it present on facebook developers site.

Comment: "Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Facebook's `Photos API` to publish the photos on a user's album.

Required permissions: `publish_stream`, `user_photos`

API: `\POST` `/photos` with the required paramters (image, name etc..)

For more details you go here: [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Comment: Could you please provide example or demo for this facebook share. Thanks,

Comment: This is not simple..! i am trying this when i provide static images it shares but when i add array of dynamic images its not working...

Comment: You can not add array of images in one go, you have to loop around and call api for each image